# BASH, терминал. Результат команды присвоить переменной

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Есть команда

```
grep -n "<div id=\"currRadar\"" "weather"
```

Хочу присвоить результат команды в переменной, что-то в стиле:

```
 variable= grep -n "<div id=\"currRadar\"" "weather"
```

Результатом хочу получить номер строки.

Гугл молчит. 
Ищу помощи у доброго содружества

Comment: > Хочу присвоить результат команды в переменной

Это достигается взятием команды в обратные  апострофы. Вот так:

*x = \`grep -n "<div id=\"currRadar\"" "weather"\`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, создаем текстовый файл из десяти строк (случайно выбраны из словаря):

```
shuf -n 10 /usr/share/dict/words >> /tmp/words
```

Содержимое файла:

```
cat /tmp/words
```

> disqualifications
>   Randi
>   carting
>   agreeing
>   tendentiousness
>   uneasier
>   outmanoeuvring
>   Frontenac
>   dragon
>   according

Допустим, необходимо найти номер строки для слова `carting`:

```
NFINDSTR=$(grep -n "carting" /tmp/words | cut -d: -f1 -)
echo $NFINDSTR
```

> 3

Так как `grep -n` возвращает строку вида `N:same_string`, то результат необходимо передать утилите `cut`, которая из стандартного ввода (аргумент `-`) по разделителю `:` (`-d:`) выделит первое поле (`-f1`).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с enSO. У меня работает.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651495

```
OUTPUT="$(ls -l)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

Конкретно с вашим примером могут быть какие-то сложности.